# Web application is not responsive on iOS?

Tags: javascript, android, css, ios, responsive-design

I tested my web app with Bluestacks mobile tester and it looks good on android devices, but when I try it on iOS it just loose responsivity (not at all but in some cases).

[Click for picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sUg2.png)

I guess ti has something to do with overflow on iOS (it's disabled or something).
Also, keyboard doesn't show automatically like in android (I must click on input to show it).

Comment: You should check it in real device to confirm the issue. You could ask a friend or I can check at my end if you could provide me the URL.

Comment: Thank you @AngrejKumar. http://muzikant.io is the URL. Please check it.

Comment: I checked everything and posting a solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its happening because of CSS display flex property. You should remove `display: flex;` from `.game .bottom .categories` in your CSS. And then it should work fine for both android and IOS.

Basically flex makes whole box compact and stick within the parent box. Its not letting it overflow. I don't know how its working fine in Android. But if you remove the display flex it will work fine in both android and ios.

Let me know if you face any issues. And you can also ask me to check so you can be sure it works fine.

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you. I overlooked that styling at all. Maybe you know is it possible to make that keyboard on iOS doesn't overlap the content and push everything to the top when I want to type?

Comment: Can you screenshot it please?

Comment: Also please verify the answer so poeple can see the answer is good for the question so other people can save their time.

Comment: I verified your answer, thank you. There is a screenshot https://imgur.com/a/E0oICEP. You see how keyboard on iOS is overlapping the content and you can't click skip button until you hide the keyboard. On android it is fit because I sat media queries for that height.